# Contour plots in R and the outer function

Tags: r

Ok, 
I managed

```
x<-seq(-1.2,1.2,0.01)
y<-x
f=outer(x,y,function(x,y)abs(x)+abs(y))
contour(x,y,f,asp=1)
```

This results exactly into what I was after...

Now let's modify the program

```
x<-seq(-1.2,1.2,0.01)
y<-x
f=outer(x,y,function(x,y)sum(abs(c(x,y))))
```

This results in

```
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 58081] do not match the length of object [1]
```

I don't understand where the problem is...

Kind regards

Comment: Ok, working hard to understand the R philosophy. I have defined the function norm1 <- function(x) sum(abs(x)) where x is a vector. Is this already wrong? Where does all the vectorization come in here?

Comment: i was hoping there is a somewhat cleaner solution. I don't have to use outer. All I want is some sort of mesh (induced by vectors x and y). Each grid point is a pair of two numbers. For those points I compute almost arbitrary functions...

Comment: Ah, so sum returns a scalar. Somewhere I have read that everything in R is a vector, even the scalars. They are vectors of length 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179771/discussion-between-tschm-and-).

Comment: What works really nice and it not to mentally puzzling is apply(expand.grid(x,y),1,f). Here I create a high and skinny matrix with two columns (all possible combinations of x and y) and then apply f along the rows of this matrix.